# Inconsistent Notepad Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a profile creator for a game I'm makeing and it isn't outputting properly. It's supposed to print

```
default
open
open
open
open
open
open
open
open
open
1
```

Instead it saves it with space between some lines, i've tried somethings but i can't fix it, can anyone help me save the text file like the example above?

(The code i'm using)

```py
debug = False


def profile_creator():
    count2 = 0
    u1 = 'Open'
    u2 = 'Open'
    u3 = 'Open'
    u4 = 'Open'
    u5 = 'Open'
    u6 = 'Open'
    u7 = 'Open'
    u8 = 'Open'
    u9 = 'Open'
    u10 = 'Open'
    content = ['HS:', '0', 'LS:', '0', 'G:', '0', '', 'LS = Last Score, HS = High Score, G = Games']
    print('> Input Save Name')
    chosen_u = input('>  ')
    chosen_u = str.lower(chosen_u)
    with open('game_info_' + chosen_u + '.txt', 'w') as f:
        for line in content:
            f.write(line)
            f.write('\n')
    f.close()
    with open('game_info_backup_' + chosen_u + '.txt', 'w') as f:
        for line in content:
            f.write(line)
            f.write('\n')
    f.close()
    with open('game_users.txt', 'r') as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        count = 1
        for line in content:
            if count == 1:
                u1 = line
            if count == 2:
                u2 = line
            if count == 3:
                u3 = line
            if count == 4:
                u4 = line
            if count == 5:
                u5 = line
            if count == 6:
                u6 = line
            if count == 7:
                u7 = line
            if count == 8:
                u8 = line
            if count == 9:
                u9 = line
            if count == 10:
                u10 = line
            if count == 11:
                count2 = line
            count += 1
    f.close()
    u1 = text_quality_control(u1)
    u2 = text_quality_control(u2)
    u3 = text_quality_control(u3)
    u4 = text_quality_control(u4)
    u5 = text_quality_control(u5)
    u6 = text_quality_control(u6)
    u7 = text_quality_control(u7)
    u8 = text_quality_control(u8)
    u9 = text_quality_control(u9)
    u10 = text_quality_control(u10)
    count2 = int(count2)
    count2 = str(count2)
    count2 = int(count2)
    count2 += 1
    if count2 == 1:
        u1 = chosen_u
    if count2 == 2:
        u2 = chosen_u
    if count2 == 3:
        u3 = chosen_u
    if count2 == 4:
        u4 = chosen_u
    if count2 == 5:
        u5 = chosen_u
    if count2 == 6:
        u6 = chosen_u
    if count2 == 7:
        u7 = chosen_u
    if count2 == 8:
        u8 = chosen_u
    if count2 == 9:
        u9 = chosen_u
    if count2 == 10:
        u10 = chosen_u
    content = [u1, '', u2, '', u3, '', u4, u5, u6, u7, u8, u9, u10, str(count2)]
    with open('game_users.txt', 'w') as f:
        for line in content:
            f.write(line)
            f.write('\n')
    f.close()


def text_quality_control(line):
    msg = str(line)
    stringer = ''
    indexer = 0
    str_length = len(msg)
    for i in range(str_length - 1):
        msg2 = msg[indexer]
        msg2 = str.lower(msg2)
        if '1' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + '1'
        if '2' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + '2'
        if '3' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + '3'
        if '4' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + '4'
        if '5' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + '5'
        if '6' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + '6'
        if '7' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + '7'
        if '8' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + '8'
        if '9' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + '9'
        if '0' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + '0'
        if 'a' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'a'
        if 'b' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'b'
        if 'c' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'c'
        if 'd' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'd'
        if 'e' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'e'
        if 'f' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'f'
        if 'g' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'g'
        if 'h' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'h'
        if 'i' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'i'
        if 'j' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'j'
        if 'k' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'k'
        if 'l' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'l'
        if 'o' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'o'
        if 'm' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'm'
        if 'n' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'n'
        if 'p' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'p'
        if 'q' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'q'
        if 'r' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'r'
        if 's' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 's'
        if 't' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 't'
        if 'u' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'u'
        if 'v' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'v'
        if 'w' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'w'
        if 'x' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'x'
        if 'y' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'y'
        if 'z' in msg2:
            stringer = stringer + 'z'
        if debug:
            print(stringer)
        indexer += 1
    if debug:
        print(stringer)
    return stringer


print('Input Save Name')
```

Comment: You need to learn how to avoid all that repetitive code. Loop over lists instead of writing dozens of hard-coded `if` statements.

Comment: It seems like `text_quality_control()` could just use `re.sub()` to remove all the characters that aren't in your list of valid characters.

Comment: Why do you convert `count2`  to an integer, then back to a string, then back to an integer?

Comment: This removes the /n after the variable, theres probably a better way to do it but thats how i do it

Comment: The first `int(count2)` already removes the `\n`. You don't need to go back to string and int again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have empty strings `''` in `content`. When you write these to the file, you get blank lines. So take them out.

```
    content = [u1, '', u2, '', u3, '', u4, u5, u6, u7, u8, u9, u10, str(count2)]
```

should be

```
    content = [u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6, u7, u8, u9, u10, str(count2)]
```